# When to use trailing backslashes

Tags: syntax

I am learning to use the `puthesis` document class. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[iupuiece,thesis]{puthesis}

\begin{document}
\title{The Theory of Everything}
\campus{West Lafayette}
\author{Kit}
\maketitle

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Take note of the `\author` line. That won't work. Out of the blue, I tried this one, and it works:

```
\author{Kit}\
```

The [documentation here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/#author) does not say anything about the trailing `\`. Is this some consistency issue with LaTeX syntax?

Comment: Did you put a space after the trailing \\?

Comment: “Won’t work” is a very vague description: There should be no need for a backslash in this place. A concept “trailing backslash” doesn’t exist at all in LaTeX.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A look in puthesis.cls shows that \author expects 2 arguments in this class:

```
\renewcommand*{\author}[2]{%
  \renewcommand*{\@@TitleAuthor}{#1}%
  \renewcommand*{\@@AbstractAuthor}{#2}%
}
```

So naturally everything explodes if this second argument is \maketitle.

Comment: Two arguments to \author is just a bad UI design. I wish all class writers would listen to [Boris Veytsman](http://river-valley.tv/class-writing-for-wizard-apprentices/)

Answer (score 3):

As Konrad Rudolph points out, there is no such thing as a trailing backslash.  (With the usual category codes,) A backslash is an escape character, and must be escaping *something*.  In this case, it's escaping the following line break, which, if I remember correctly, is usually interpreted to mean the same as an escaped space, which, again if I remember correctly, is used to tell TeX that you want exactly one space where it might otherwise put 0 or more than 1:

```
Mr.\ Not-a-sentence
$bad\ way\ to\ put\ text\ in\ math\ mode$
```

(UPDATE:  Probably a better example is the traditional use to prevent space-swallowing after a macro, as in `\TeX\ is fascinating`.)  As Ulrike points out [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/when-to-use-trailing-backslashes/3019#3019), your original document attempts to pass the macro `\maketitle` as the second argument to \author, which breaks somewhere down the line (presumably when `\@@AbstractAuthor` is used); whereas the fixed document instead passes the macro `\<par>` as the second argument, which'll probably compile, but will put a space everywhere the abstract-author's name might be expected.

Comment: Assuming nothing has changed the `\endlinechar`, the second argument being passed (what you called `\<par>`) is `\^^M`.

Comment: TH., thanks!  I actually discovered this shortly after posting by reading another one of your comments (which I can no longer find).  Am I correct that \^^M by default (say, in Plain TeX) has the same effect as \ ?

Comment: @L Spice: Yes, that is correct; see p. 8 of the TeXbook, or search for "\def\^^M" in `plain.tex`.