# How do I read the texdoc for the letter document class?

Tags: document-classes, texdoc, documentation

I am reading the `texdoc` for the `letter` document class. But it doesn't say anything about getting started. I think this is a commented source code document. Yes, it lists all the features of the `letter` class, but it doesn't say anything about how to use them in practice. There is no tutorial or walkthrough or something similar. To illustrate what I mean:
[image]

This question is related to the one I asked about [reading commented sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/are-there-guidelines-on-how-to-read-commented-sources-of-latex-packages). I noticed that most documentation is in this form, which is rather frustrating. In contrast, the `memoir` and `pgfmanual` are superb examples of documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no user documentation for the letter class, just as there is no user documentation for the other standard LaTeX classes; users were expected, back in the day, to buy Lamport's book as a manual.

The letter class is generally considered sub-standard compared to the alternatives. Robin Fairbairn's [FAQ answer on the matter](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterclass) lists the alternatives.