# What type of .sty or document class will be good for thesis?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, thesis, report

I am writing my thesis but i want to write it with Latex as my University do not have a document class or .sty as i used to see other university. Could any one know the the .sty that has the under lists specification. Thank you all and looking forward in seeing your reply.

1. Times new roman
2. Double spacing,
3. Chapter and Heading 16pts fonts size,
4. Heading space 48pts, paragraphs 24pts space.
5. section 14pts font size,
6. subsection 12pts font size,
7. figure and table caption 12pts and single spacing;
8. Paper A4 with margins; top 2.5cm, bottom 2.5cm, right 2.5cm and left 4.0cm,

Comment: [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: `KOMAscript`'s `scrreprt` is my preferred class for theses.

Comment: a really good survey by peter flynn of existing thesis classes is referenced in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51909/579) to the question "How to write a LaTeX class file for my thesis".

Comment: If those are all the requirements, you can use `book`, the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for the page layout, [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) for the spacing, [`caption`](http;//www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for the captions and [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for the sectional unit headings.

Comment: At least in the U.S., a list of 8 things is never the complete list of formatting requirements for a thesis. It's not even the complete list of formatting requirements for the title page. (I know from the A4 paper that the author isn't in the US, but still -- had to get a dig in at graduate school administrators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you look at [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) which is pretty much designed for the job. It's what I am using for mine. It has a great amount of simplified customisation, that should help meet your requirements and has excellent documentation

Answer (score 7):

As @TomBrien mentioned, [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir/). Other notes:

- You want a class, not a package. A thesis must (normally) be formatted a particular way, and that's what a class controls. Packages are for code or commands that could be used in lots of different types of documents. See [LaTeX 2e for class and package writers](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/clsguide.pdf) for more information. Base your class off `memoir` (or whatever other base class you decide to use).
- I've got a thesis class based off `memoir` that I've developed over the last several years ([development branch](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk), [stable branch](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/branches/stable), [ZIP downloads](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/svn-releases/ttuthesis/)). I haven't found a formatting problem that `memoir` couldn't handle.
- You don't have to make your thesis class as complicated as mine. I tried to make a hard and fast rule that students would never have to edit the .cls file, and that I wanted to automatically use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). This meant that I had to include extra code to let students add packages before `hyperref` was loaded, and other packages after `hyperref` was loaded.
- Take each requirement as a small problem to be solved, and use the `memoir` documentation (or others' code, if needed) to find the solution. But critically examine any code you find to make sure there's not a `memoir`-specific solution in the documentation. For example, you need to set a margin size for A4 paper: **all** of Chapter 2 in the `memoir` manual is about margins and related layout, but if you just Google a solution, you'll probably find people recommending the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package or lower-level commands. I'd default to the `memoir` version of the solution whenever possible.