# Question about suitablity of Latex for university works with strictly specified page layout

Tags: report

I don't have prior experience with Latex so I'm wondering if it would meet my needs well.

So I need to write some reports on my studies in university. Problem is, we don't seem to have Latex template for these works and the document layout is strictly ordered. So for example the left margin must be 3.5cm, right margin 3.0cm, page number must be at the center of the page and not at the bottom of the page. Line spacing must be "1.5" and there must be certain number of lines between paragraphs.

I know Latex is great for making good looking papers, but what about situation like this, where there are stupid rules for page layout, which must be followed? Would it be hard for me, as the Latex newbie, to meet these criteria with Latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you check whether there is already a `LaTeX` template for your university at hand. And the answer to your questions is 'yes'.

Comment: You can set the margins with the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package, line spacing with the [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package, and paragraph spacing with the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package.

Comment: @ChrisS or you can set *everything* (not really, but most) with a KOMA-Script class :P

Comment: It's fairly easy to follow these rules with LaTeX. I have seen much worse, believe me!

Comment: @ChristianH Yes, I checked our university's website and asked from the teacher, but unfortunately neither were aware of the existing LaTeX template.

Comment: So it won't require me to create the whole new template from scratch? So I should be able to quite easily modify some other template for my needs? Do you have any suggestion with what tools will I need to study at first? I already found The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX which I started to read but then again, I won't need all the nice Mathematical things at first. Just plain text with pictures and tables and bibliography tables and all the requirements from the school. Thank you everybody!

Comment: Check with the math and physics departments to see if they have an in-house LaTeX template the university doesn't keep up with. I've got more advice about this at [What type of .sty or document class will be good for thesis?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163704/3345)

Comment: I would say this: the fact that the layout is strictly defined partly undermines the benefits of LaTeX. If you are itching to use it just because or you will gain particular satisfaction from doing so, by all means use it. As others have said, LaTeX can easily cope with these sorts of requirements. But if you have no burning desire to use LaTeX, your life will probably be easier if you stick to whatever standard template other people use and whatever standard software they use it with. Also, what do you mean 'at the centre of the page'? Top centre? Or really centre? Former is easy. Latter...?

Comment: This seems unlikely to get answered: it's as much an opinion as anything else whether the outcome is worth the effort. All of the things you mention are doable: individual questions on the site cover I think all of them.