# Modifying a thesis template: abstract environment

Tags: templates, abstract

I am using a thesis template available [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). I have a problem in working with this template:

I would like to have a 'normal' abstract, directly after the title page. In this template the abstract is pimped with all kinds of additional information. I would just like to have the lay-out of the usual `\begin{abstract}` environment. I deleted all commands in the template concerning the abstract part, but I keep getting this additional stuff.

Comment: you've just posted three questions regarding "imcompatibilities" between what you need in a thesis template and what you're trying to use.  may i suggest that perhaps you should consider a different template.  take a look at [LaTeX templates for writing a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326/579) and the two tugboat articles by peter flynn cited in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51909/579).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this template uses the [`book` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) (which is similar to [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)), we can just copy the `abstract` environment definition from there into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries Abstract
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{Abstract}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries Abstract\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother
```

The only difference in the above code in comparison to the `abstract` environment as defined in `report.cls` is that I've `\renewenvironment` the `abstract` environment and used an explicit `Abstract` instead of the now-undefined `\abstractname`.

[image]